# Terraform keep complaining duplicate block while creating azure vpn gateway using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

Objective: Trying to create vpn gateway using terraform on Azure

What I tried:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw" {
  name = "vng-orpcb-hub-${var.env}-we"
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  type = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = true
  enable_bgp = false
  sku = "VpnGw1AZ"
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip.id    
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.gatewaysubnetdata.id
  }
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig1"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-secondary.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.gatewaysubnetdata.id
  }
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig2"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-vpn.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.gatewaysubnetdata.id
  }

  dynamic "vpn_client_configuration" {
    for_each = tomap({ for k, v in var.audience : k => v })
    content {
    address_space = ["10.100.0.0/24"]
    vpn_auth_types = ["AAD"]
    aad_tenant = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    aad_audience = vpn_client_configuration.value
    aad_issuer = "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
    }  
  }
}
```

My variable.tf:

```
variable "audience" {
  description = "respective environments"
  type = any
  default = {
    dev = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
    stg = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
    prod = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
}
}
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Error: Too many vpn_client_configuration blocks
│ 
│   on main.tf line 933, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw":
│  933:     content {
│ 
│ No more than 1 "vpn_client_configuration" blocks are allowed
```

I am not sure where I am giving multiple client configuration here

I am trying to pass in audience value from that variable map based on environment code that i pass, i.e dev,stg,prod etc

Please suggest.

Comment: `dynamic "vpn_client_configuration" {` **<=** there you are creating multiple `vpn_client_configuration` blocks if `tomap({ for k, v in var.audience : k => v })` has more than one entry.

Comment: Yup, the variable audience has three keys, hence there are three blocks.

Comment: Do you want one VPN GW for 3 audiences? That is not possible. You can have one VPN GW per audience and use the `terraform. Workspace` variable for each environment

Comment: Hi all , I have solved it without ``for_each`` and with just  `audience = var.audience[var.env]` Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Removed  `for_each` and
just `audience = var.audience[var.env]` Thanks for suggestions.